# Laravel 5.5: Auth does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using the following code to login using Auth.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $remember = $request->input('remember');
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('home');
    }
    return view('app.login')->with('errors', 1);
}
```

The attempt function returns true, so hashing should not be the problem. When I was redirected to the 'home' page, I was still not authenticated. @auth sections in blade templates were not shown, and Auth::check() returned false. It seems that the auth information is not stored in the session.
Do I need to modify my User model? Here is my config/auth:

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        /*
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
        */
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

My model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Have you used any guards? Show the config/auth

Comment: 'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

           'api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],

Comment: 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

Comment: can you edit the question with the information you provided so it is easier to read.

Comment: I believe that you are authenticated but it seems to me that you do not store the information of the connected user

Comment: I agree. I'm just wondering how to store that information. Do I need to modify config/session?

Comment: display in view. @if(Auth::check())<p>Logged in</p>@else<p>Not Logged in</p>@endif  After each statement put it on to a new line and see what you get.

Comment: I was authenticated right after the attempt function returned, but logged out when I clicked another link.